# How to see number of iterations taken by solveOneNonlinearEquation function in modelica?

Tags: modelica

I'm using the solveOneNonlinearEquation solver in Modelica which uses Brent's method to find the root of the nonlinear equation. However, I need to know how many iterations were taken by Brent's method in order to compare the rate of convergence with another method like fixed-point iteration. The inbuilt solver does not have the option to output 'NumberOfIterations" and hence I tried writing my own Brent's method function and placing a counter.
However I have to input a function to this function and get the error "The type prefixes flow, input and output shall only be applied for a structured component, if no element of the component has a corresponding type prefix of the same category."

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

The code of `Modelica.Math.Nonlinear.solveOneNonlinearEquation` is not encrypted. Simply copy it and create your own `solveOneNonlinearEquation` which contains a counter for the iterations, like

```
function solveOneNonlinearEquation
...
protected 
  Integer iterations = 0;
...
algorithm
...
  // Search loop
  while not found loop
    iterations := iterations + 1;
...
  end while;

  Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("Iterations: " + String(iterations));
...
end solveOneNonlinearEquation;
```

For the usage of the function with functions as input, see the example `Modelica.Math.Nonlinear.Examples.solveNonlinearEquations1`.